# Deployment Issue: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 94477506-8488 (-1165391008)

Tags: apex, deployment, ant, gack

I am using ANT tool for deploying code into my org and today, when I am trying to deploy the code, it is throwing following exception in about 281 classes:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 94477506-8488 (-1165391008)
```

I understand that this is Salesforce internal error and we need to raise a case with Salesforce about it but does anyone have any idea what it can be?

Comment: I think it's [gack](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169590/is-this-a-bug-in-apex-compiler). Similar kind of error I encountered though it was in Apex context.

Comment: Hmm. Did it deploy fine before? Are you now on summer 17. Seems there are issues with package installs containing lightning components. Maybe that extends to deployments to. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI&title=package-install-fails-with-error-no-controller-named-js-xxxxxx-found-or-we-couldn-t-retrieve-the-design-time-component-information-for-component

Comment: Download latest files from _Force.com Migration Tool Download_ [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) and try. Update your package.xml accordingly. If it does not work, get in touch with Salesforce.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, a gack of this nature revolves around a single point of failure, one component that failed to compile. Once a gack occurs, all future components will fail with the same gack. Check the first component where this gack occurred for validity, or try deploying everything *except* the one file. Without contacting support, it's kind of a guessing game, but you can usually narrow down the suspects by trial and error. The error code itself is an auto-generated number and not related to an error code like Microsoft typically has. That specific error code simply means that a particular component failed with the same stack trace that matched others with the same stack trace.

Comment: Yes, Its absolutely correct. If one component get failed, rest of all the components got failed. We can run the code by escaping the failing component. The fail component will avail at error results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exception message from salesforce:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Db Proxy diff during transitioning to new compiler, blowing up to prevent bad db state! on id null"
```

There are some internal processes on Salesforce servers which sometimes cause this error. I deployed it again today and it gave me exact error which I fixed and then, the code deployed without any error.

My Suggestion is that when you see error like this, just stop wasting your time on deployment and do some productive work. Try next day and it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this occur many times in vscode - it usually is one file with compiler error - but impossible to see which one in vscode with so much noise it hurts my eyes.

So I went the the Deployment Status page in my org and viewed details on the failed deploy - the very first test in the list that failed was the culprit. It is much easier to read here.

The most recent one was a simple assignment from one type to another not matching.  I sure miss resharper that points out compiler errors immediately.